# Efficient way of simplify sum of product of multiple polynomials

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials, computational-algebra

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}, B \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I'm trying to compute the coefficients of $n$ polynomials $C_i = (c_0^i, c_1^i, \cdots, c_{n-1}^i)$.

where $\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} c_j^i x^j = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} B_k \prod_{l=0, l \neq i}^{n-1}(1+A_{lk}x)$.

Right now I have tried with enumerate each $i$ of $n$ and then enumerate each $j$ of $m$ compute the coefficients for  $\displaystyle\prod_{l=0, l \neq i}^{n-1}(1+A_{lk}x)$ first and then sum them up.

And I'm wondering if there are any more efficient approaches?

For example, using a toy example with $n=3, m=2$:

$$
A = \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
    a_1 & b_1  \\
    a_2 & b_2  \\
    a_3 & b_3  \\
\end{array} \right], B = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} z_1 \\
z_2\end{array}\right]
$$

I'm looking to compute for three polynomial $f_1, f_2, f_3$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_1(x) & = z_1(1+a_2x)(1+a_3x) \\
& + z_2(1+b_2x)(1+b_3x)
\end{aligned}
$$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_2(x) & = z_1(1+a_1x)(1+a_3x) \\
& + z_2(1+b_1x)(1+b_3x)
\end{aligned}
$$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
f_3(x) & = z_1(1+a_1x)(1+a_2x) \\
& + z_2(1+b_1x)(1+b_2x)
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly, this is only for illustration purposes, in my real problem, $m$ can be really big at the scale of $2^{20}$, $n$ is typically at $1000$ scale, and I need to do the same type of computing with different $A, B$ for millions of times.

Comment: I suggest you let a Computer Algebra System do the arithmetic automatically.

Comment: @Somos in my real setting, $m$ can be really big and efficiency is really desired.

Comment: I suggest that you state explicitly in your question what "real" problem your are trying to solve. That is, what the "real setting" is and how big is "really big" and that gives lower bounds on how "efficient" you can get the results theoretically.

Comment: @Somos thank you for your suggestions, I've updated the problem statement

Comment: Okay, then you have potentially $10^9$ numbers. What are you going to do with those numbers? You may not need to calculate all of them to solve your problem.

Comment: no, after aggregation, there will be $n$ length $n$ coefficient vectors, and each is going to do a dot product with such a constant vector $(1/{n-1 \choose 0}, 1/{n-1 \choose 1}, \cdots,  1/{n-1 \choose n-1})$, and report back to the end user with $n$ numbers.  Recall, $n$ is small at 1000 scale.

Comment: Okay, that is more like it. You only need to crunch it down to $n$ numbers. There may be application of parallel computing and GPU usage here. Also, I assume you only need single precision floating point arithmetic? Please include these important details in the body of your question.